# From Postgres data to specific format of DateTime.Value

Tags: c#, postgresql, parsing, datetimepicker

This may seem quite basic, and I know there must be a simple answer for this, but I've been stuck here for quite a while now.

I have column in a DB that stores time. Since I altered the format in my app to only show "HH tt" in that DateTimePicker control (e.g. 9 AM). When I insert the new entry, I end up with data as "17:00:00" in my DB.

Insert is not the problem though, but when I try to fetch a specific entry in the DB and get the app to show the time it just fetched in the DateTimePicker the DB originally got it from, I keep getting errors. I think I just have to parse the obtained data somehow, but I can't seem to find any way to do it.

Please help!

Comment: (Posted on behalf of @NathanKempter who has no sufficient rep to post comments) What errors are you getting?